# Is it right to flag performance related questions based on miscalculations?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

As correctly pointed out in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21096867/771663), SO hosts many questions where the OP asks for reasons behind a performance difference that later turns out to be based on wrong premises.

In these cases, being the question possibly not useful to anybody, is it right to flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: I've closed the question as "problem can't be reproduced."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply provide an answer that explains the invalid assumption made by the question, when a question has invalid assumptions.  A good answer would also hopefully explain the correct conclusions to be drawn based on valid assumptions.  The question doesn't need to be closed.

In just the same way that if someone asks "Why is the sky Green?" you can reply that the sky is in fact Pink (with a suitable explanation as to why that is the case), rather than closing the question due to an invalid premise.

Comment: And yet, this happens *all the time*, at least in the [C++] tag.

Comment: What if the question is worse? Maybe more like "I saw something really strange!" "Really?" "No"

Comment: @Massimiliano Then that would be closable as `"This question was caused by a problem that can't be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."`

Comment: This particular case seems to be pretty clear-cut.